# How to insert kbd macros in Yas-snippets?

Tags: yasnippet, keyboard-macros

I'm trying to learn how to:

1. Define a kbd-macro, (here I'm using kbd-macros, because I'm bad at elisp currently).
2. Letting that to be executed when yas-snippet to expand. (here I'm struggling with)

---

**My current state**:
I want to make following in latex equation. First write `a_x /` then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to get `\frac{a_x}{}` (in here `/` as yas-snippet key).

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: 1slash-frac_one_word
# key: /
# type: command
# --
(fset 'gry-test-frac-kbdmacro
   (kmacro-lambda-form [C-left ?\\ ?f ?r ?a ?c ?\{ C-right ?\} ?\{ ?\} left return return up tab] 0 "%d"))
(gry-test-frac-kbdmacro)
```

Basically, I first defined kbd-macro, and then inserted it's definition to the snippet, and then running it. This works.

---

**My concerns/tries**: Every time this snippet expands, `gry-test-frac-kbdmacro` gets defined again and again. Which seems to me inefficient. Also I don't want to write it's definition in other places like `init.el`. So tried following:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: 1slash-frac_one_word
# key: /
# type: command
# --
(kmacro-lambda-form [C-left ?\\ ?f ?r ?a ?c ?\{ C-right ?\} ?\{ ?\} left return return up tab] 0 "%d")
```

Basically, I tried to run the things inside of the macro definition (without defining it). However this doesn't work.

---

- Could you explain me why 2-nd snippet doesn't work?
- And Is there any way to run what's inside of macro without defining it first?

Comment: @Arktik you should write your comment up as an answer

Comment: @Arktik thank you, your comment is the answer I was looking for. Please write your comment as answer, So I can accept it & close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to run a macro without binding it to a name, use `execute-kbd-macro`. In your example, this would be:

```
(execute-kbd-macro [C-left ?\\ ?f ?r ?a ?c ?\{ C-right ?\} ?\{ ?\} left return return up tab])
```

Your second snippet creates a function, it needs to be evaluated for it to take effect. The "lambda-form" part refers to an anonymous function as the keyword `lambda` is used to define anonymous functions. See https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Anonymous-Functions.html

Answer (score 2):

The second snippet doesn't work because all you're doing is defining the keyboard macro lambda form; you're not doing anything with it. Use `execute-kbd-macro` as @Arktik suggests (see `C-h f execute-kbd-macro`). If you want to be more "lispy" you could do a snippet like the following:

```lisp
# type: command
# key: /
# name: test2
# --
(backward-word)
(insert "\\frac{")
(forward-word)
(insert "}{}")
(left-char)
```

Note that yasnippet will wrap that in a `progn` on save.

But personally I wouldn't do that. I'd type my numerator, select backwards over it, then execute my snippet. Something like:

```lisp
# name: test
# binding: C-c C-y
# --
\frac{`yas-selected-text`}{$1} $0
```

Note that you can't trigger the snippet via `key:`, you need to set a keybinding `C-c C-y` in this example.

But I wouldn't even do that. I'd just use the default `latex-mode` "frac" snippet which is:

```lisp
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: frac
# key: frac
# --
\frac{${1:numerator}}{${2:denominator}}$0
```

If you find yourself doing a lot of "repetitive but slightly different" text, you might want to check out [Auto-YASnippet](https://github.com/abo-abo/auto-yasnippet) which describes itself as a hybrid of keyboard macros and YASnippet.

Comment: Just to add to the above, also have a look at `cdlatex` package for math stuff in LaTeX, https://github.com/cdominik/cdlatex.

Comment: @nega, Thank you for your comment. As you mentioned about @Arktik 's comment about `execute-kbd-macro` is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: My reasoning about not to use `frac` snippet in `latex-mode` is that I write numerator first and then realize I need to write up as `\frac{}{}`. (It's just how my thinking process works I guess). To be honest  I still use this snippet mainly until now.`

Comment: My reasoning about not to use `# binding: C-c C-y` or any other binding is that it has more keystrokes than simple `/` + `tab`. (also not to mention about thinking / remembering about this as clearly)

Comment: Thank you very much about the `elsip` code. When I learn elsip properly I will rewrite every kbd-macros in elisp. Until then I will use `ecute-kbd-macro` from @Arktik 's comment.